# How do I connect a comment table to another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A pretty basic RoR question that I can't seem to find an answer to online:

I have two independent tables that were created with a scaffold. 
lunches and comments. Relationships were not established during the scaffolding. I can redo the comments scaffold if needed.

I need to be able to take in and then display the related comments to every lunch in the lunch index view. Can someone tell me how to do that?

I edited the models\comment.rb to:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :lunch
end
```

I edited the models\lunch.rb to:

```
class Lunch < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In the lunches view I have a loop that lists all the lunches columns:

```
<tbody>
    <% @lunches.each do |lunch| %>
      <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even')%>">

          <td><%= lunch.company %></td>
          <td><%= lunch.person %></td>
          <td><%= lunch.email_submit_lunch %></td>
          <td><%= lunch.company_contact %></td>
          <td class="list_description"><%= truncate(strip_tags(lunch.description), length: 40) %></td>
          <td><%= lunch.date %></td>
          <td><%= lunch.price %></td>

          <td class="list_actions"><%= link_to 'Show', lunch %></td>
          <td class="list_actions"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_lunch_path(lunch), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          <td class="list_actions"><%= link_to 'Destroy', lunch, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

** Edit: I have redone the comments table to contain the lunch_id foreign key. How would I pass this foreign key (lunch_id) from the lunch view into the comment creation process?

Comment: I am new to ruby but know databases pretty well. So, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use comments relation on lunch model.

If you established it correctly, then you can try something like:

```
<tbody>
<% @lunches.each do |lunch| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even')%>">

      <td><%= lunch.company %></td>
      <td><%= lunch.person %></td>
      <td><%= lunch.email_submit_lunch %></td>
      <td><%= lunch.company_contact %></td>
      <td class="list_description"><%= truncate(strip_tags(lunch.description), length: 40) %></td>
      <td><%= lunch.date %></td>
      <td><%= lunch.price %></td>

      <td>
        <%- lunch.comments.each do |comment| %>
          <p><%= comment.body %></p>
        <% end %>
      </td>

      <td class="list_actions"><%= link_to 'Show', lunch %></td>
      <td class="list_actions"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_lunch_path(lunch), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      <td class="list_actions"><%= link_to 'Destroy', lunch, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

UPD:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    lunch = Lunch.find(params[:lunch_id])
    lunch.comments.create!(comment_params)
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params[:comment].permit(:body)
  end
end
```

In such case, when you post form to create comment, you should add lunch_id to form params, like:

lunch_path(lunch_id: lunch.id)

This is the main idea. But implementation can depend of your business logic. For example where do you locate new comment form and other conditions.

Comment: So, my problem is establishing the connection. What else do I need to do besides editing the model files? I believe I would need to pass the lunch_id to the comments table somehow?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you did it. Yes, you should add lunch_id to comments table. Just run rails generate migration AddLunchIdToComments lunch_id:integer

And then run rake db:migrate

Comment: спасибо. I re created the scaffold to include the lunch ID in the comments. Any advice on how to pass the lunch_id in the lunch view to the comments create view?

Comment: This helps a lot, I will try going through the comments controller to get the lunch_id params. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention it in the description, but you will need to add the column `lunch_id` to the comments table (if you haven't already) for the relationship to work.

By defining that `Lunch` `has_many :comments` Rails will create a instance method for `Lunch` called `comments` that will return the associated comments.

In your view you can do something like this to display the comments.

```
<tbody>
<% @lunches.each do |lunch| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even')%>">
      <td><%= lunch.company %></td>
      <td><%= lunch.person %></td>
      <td><%= lunch.email_submit_lunch %></td>
      <td><%= lunch.company_contact %></td>
      <td class="list_description"><%= truncate(strip_tags(lunch.description), length: 40) %></td>
      <td><%= lunch.date %></td>
      <td><%= lunch.price %></td>

      <ul>          
        <% lunch.comments.each do |comment| %>
          <li><%= comment %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>

      <td class="list_actions"><%= link_to 'Show', lunch %></td>
      <td class="list_actions"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_lunch_path(lunch), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      <td class="list_actions"><%= link_to 'Destroy', lunch, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I can create the lunch_id. But how would each comment entry know to be associated with that lunch _id? I am assuming something in the lunch view would need to be passed to the comments\new.html.erb (where comments are created)

Comment: Correct, when you create the comment you will also need to set the lunch_id that it's associated with.

Comment: so, could I create a lunch controller method that creates an instance variable to be passed on to the comments\new.html.erb?

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely need to establish a FK for lunches in the comments table.  Adjust your migration to include:

```
create_table "comments" do |t|
  t.string   :body
  t.integer  :lunch_id
end
```

Then to display the comments, just loop through the `comments` on each `lunch` in your index view:

```
<td>
  <% lunch.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p><%= comment.body %></p>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

Comment: Got it, I can create the FK but, when a user is creating a comment, how would rails know what lunch to relate it to? How would I pass the appropriate lunch key to the comments table?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you created both model scaffolds independently. This means that your db tables are not connected.

To actually make an association you have to add a column to comments table "lunch_id" (which would tell Rails to which lunch does the comment belong).

You can do this by running

```
rails g migration AddLunchIdToComment
```

after that open the newly created migration file and add the line

```
add_column, :comments, :lunch_id, :integer
```

inside the change function.

after that do `rake db:migrate`

Now you can access lunch related comments with `lunch.comments` method inside your view loop. This should make your code work (don't forget to restart the server).